# multiple urls hosted only one needs https

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https, multiple-sites

I have several sites on one server but one the urls needs to be https.

for examples sake:
http://www.example1.com/
https://www.example2.com/

i've been using htaccess to force https but it does it to ALL the urls essentially breaking all except that one URL i have a SSL cert for.

how can i force https on that one site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a double-condition in your htaccess:
- condition 1: check for `www.example2.com` **only**
- condition 2: check for `http` requests **only**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This way, every `http` url from `www.example2.com` will go to `https` equivalent